# Is there an easier way to decode a number from text than this?

Tags: java, json, string, parsing, numbers

The following code is from my simplex JSON decoder

```
private Number decodeNumber() {
    int start = pos;
    boolean integer = true;
    while (buffer[pos++] != ',') {
        if (pos == buffer.length) {
            break;
        }
        if (buffer[pos] == '.') {
            integer = false;
        }
    }
    pos--;
    final String value = new String(buffer, start, pos - start);
    Number number;
    if (integer) {
        try {
            number = Integer.parseInt(value);
        } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
            number = Long.parseLong(value);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            number = Float.parseFloat(value);
        } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
            number = Double.parseDouble(value);
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

It seems quite tedious deciding the type of the number but I can't think of a better way of doing so. Are there any alternatives other than looking for a decimal in the value/throwing exceptions?

Comment: Please post a sample buffer input string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parse method of NumberFormat:

```
NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the initial scan, and then just try `Integer.parseInt(), Float.parseFloat()` and `Double.parseDouble(),` in that order, until you don't get a `NumberFormatException.`